# create new menuInflater or getMenuInflater() from activity?

Tags: android, android-menu

I'm creating new option menu inside fragment but after reading 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
which said to it's better to use context-application than context-activity, I'm afraid to use getActivity().getMenuInflater()

So, actually which one better

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuInflater mInflater = new MenuInflater(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mInflater.inflate(R.menu.simple_menu, menu);
}
```

Or the one call activity

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuInflater mInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    mInflater.inflate(R.menu.simple_menu, menu);

}
```

and, what's the differences between the two of 'em? or..both are just the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are very similar.  Looking through the MenuInflator's source, the only thing it uses the context for is to access the resource files.  So the specific context doesn't matter to the MenuInflator.

As for memory leaks, the article you reference says

> The most obvious [way to avoid memory leaks] is to avoid escaping the
>   context outside of its own scope

Unless you pass the MenuInflator (or Menu) to another class then it is contained in the activity and won't be leaked.

**EDIT**

In addition `Activity.getMenuInflator()` is just a convenience method for `new MenuInflator()`.  In fact this is the method inside the Activity class:

```
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return new MenuInflater(this);
}
```

It is usually better to use convenience methods since they allow for the underlying implementation to change in future versions without you having to change your code.  For example if the above method is modified to return a cached instance instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: yeah, but creating "new" menuInflater sounds like it will eat more memory than "get" menuInflater...

and you said it won't be leaked if I don't pass the menuInflator to another class, I call this inside the fragment class not the fragment activity, so if I call getMenuInflator won't it be "call the menuInflator from another class"?

Comment: @GAO-tsukai I missed your question about this method. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MenuInflater` instance that is passed to the method `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` (notice the 2nd argument)
There's no real difference, because normally you will "forget" it as soon as you finish using it, but why would you need to create one if you already have one from the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Change from this :

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
```

To this:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
```